# Ruby on Rails: Selecting multiple items of model and insert them in a new table

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm fairly new to Rails. I'm trying to build a small application.
I have 4 models Order, Room, Item and Inventory.

I want to show the user a list of items (Already present in the database) Room wise. User has the option to select items along with the quantity from that list. Once the selection is done, the selected items should be saved to Inventory table.

Inventory table has item_id, order_id and quantity.

Upon Continue it should display the Items of another room and so on until all the rooms are done.

I'm stuck at this point on how to go ahead.

My view file of the above page looks like this

```
<div class="row">
   <h6>Living Room</h6>
</div>
<% @items.each do |item| %>
    <p "name1"><%= item.name.capitalize %> </p>
<% end %>
<a href="#" >Next Room</a>
```

Is there any rails way of recognizing all the selected items along with the quantity and creating all the records at once?

Comment: Is your view structured like a form? It doesn't seem to be.

Comment: right now its not. I want to structure it to a form but could not do it (Decide the action of the form). If I could structure it in a such a way that I can create all entries of Inventory table at a time (inserting hidden fields for order_id and item_id) then thats best for me.

Comment: If you want to send an array with POST, you should use name like `itemquantity[]`... If you send multiple objects with the same name, I think only the last one will be submitted.

Comment: @RubyRacer, DO you want me to structure a form to my create method of Inventory controller, where the form fields will have names like itemquantity[]?

Comment: I don't want you to do anything, I'm just telling you how data is submitted by forms. If you have to submit an array of objects, then you will have to restructure accordingly. @KPheasey 's answer is on the track of showing you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an items array would be a good solution:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  ...
  = text_field_tag "item[#{item.id}]", value: 0 
  ...
<% end %>
```

Then in the controller action:

```
def update
  params[:item].each do |item_id, quantity|
    next if quantity == 0
    inventory = Inventory.find_or_initialize_by(item_id: item_id, order_id: current_order.id)
    inventory.quantity = quantity
    inventory.save
  end
end
```

I'm not too sure where you get the order id from, so I just assume you have a `current_order` method.

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit newbie to rails. So could you please eloberate  on the answer? Does my view code should be structured in a form and the action is to the update method of items controller?

Comment: I think I have understood what you meant. I have made a few changes to your code and looks like its working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm facing another problem regarding the above question, I have edited the question. Could you please help me on that too?